# Umbraco Rich text editor on next tab

Tags: content-management-system, umbraco, rte

Hi this is my first Umbraco build, so I'm not sure if this is a common occurrence, but for the rich text editor I went through this process to create my own styles.

http://umbraco.tv/videos/umbraco-v7/implementor/fundamentals/stylesheets-and-javascript/setting-up-rte-styles/documentation

However on my data types I've got another tab, which uses a grid structure within that grid structure there are rich text editor options. The problem I'm having is that the rich text editor isn't pulling through my styles.

Is there a way to make the rich text editor styles universal across my umbraco site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Richtext editor inside the grid has another, different than default, configuration. You can find it in Grid data type which is used on page which you want to edit.